# How to merge two class styles using sass?

Tags: sass

how can we merge two styles blocks of different classes which are having same properties except "Padding" as shown in below code in to one block.

Here i am using SASS(Syntactically Awesome Style Sheets).Any help would be appreciable. Thank you.

```css
.bookstyle {
    color:  $alt-dark-blue;
    padding-left:82.1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    clear: both;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.pagestyle {
    color:  $alt-dark-blue;
 clear : both;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way of doing this is to have one extend the other. Here's an example of it

```
.bookstyle {
    @extend .pagestyle;

    padding-left:82.1px;

}

.pagestyle {
    color:  red;
      clear : both;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Alternatively you could use mixins to add the required rules.

I'm assuming you're using the SCSS syntax for Sass by the way

Comment: Thank you for your response. It works by the way. yes i am using SCSS syntax for sass.

Comment: One small question Mr.Luke, can we able to provide a value to padding-left based on resolution of the page instead 82.1px?

Comment: The closest you'' be able to get is percentages or viewport units. Sass can't really help you there as it's compiled before it reaches the browser

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@extend` rule

```
%pagestyle {
    color:  $alt-dark-blue;
    clear : both;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.bookstyle {
    @extend %pagestyle;
    padding-left:82.1px;
}
```